# Make MVC Url.Action compilable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am starting to have management problems with my controllers when using URL.Action. I could define constants for all controller actions but that seems rather overbearing. I remember seeing a tool somewhere that would add compile time checking for controller methods. Anyone have advice?

Comment: You mean MvcContrib and using actual controller and action names?

Comment: Thanks, I would rather Use Url.Action(SomeClass.SomeMethod) as opposed to Url.Action("SomeAction.SomeMethod"). I will look into MvcContrib, thanks.

Comment: MvcContrib uses `@Url.Action<UserController>(a => a.Display(userId))` as an example. You bind using expressions, not strings.

Comment: I see and thanks for the explanation. I think that is better than the tool that would make types of all controller methods. I will up vote and do some research :)

Comment: One focus for me personally, is to keep external code minimal. Would MvcContrib refactoring cause a problem with an existing MVC.App?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but doesn't hurt to back it up/archive it before implementing.